# Stepper motor just oscillates with arduino and L293D

Tags: arduino-uno, stepper

I am trying to control my stepper motor using arduino duemilanove, with L293D as H-bridge. I use a NEMA 17, stepper motor 42BYGH-036B I have used both the default example program from arduino IDE, and also from; http://www.electronicshub.org/stepper-motor-control-using-arduino/

But in both cases, The motor just oscillates, without going for rotation.

The following is the connection, I have been using;

[image: connection diagram]

Comment: Please edit your question to include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of code, not just snippets. Minimal means you've stripped away irrelevant stuff, just leaving what's needed to show the problem. Complete means all the library names are shown, all the variable declarations, and all the function definitions – so people don't have to waste time guessing what you did or what you meant. Verifiable means it can be compiled and tested, allowing other people to test their theories about the problem